# Very dark materials Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

So I finally gave this model textures and materials and it looks fine in material view but in render view the whole model is just pitch black. Strangely enough, the render looks fine in Blender Render mode. Here is my nodes setup/material view:
[image]

Here is download link for mesh with materials and image textures with UV's :
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mfyoougy6qflmdz/AABd0cniihD1OHWT77W00HN3a?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to disable the alpha channel for the normal maps by unchecking the "Use Alpha" boxes.

Comment: I don't know why this solution was downvoted, it nailed it.
The problem is indeed the alpha channel in the normal map. A normal map shouldn't have an alpha channel as it's information not intended to be composited.
Turning off the use alpha checkbox in the image viewer for each texture will solve the problem, but in order to avoid it in the future make sure that your normal maps don't have alpha channels. If you created them yourself using a painting program, make sure you're not using transparency.If you created them in a specialized program and it exported them that way, consider reporting

Comment: Also notice that your model is huge (i think it was like 78 meters high). Keep in mind that in a physically based renderer light intensity falls off with distance (inverse quadratic proportion), so size and distance matter.
Scale your models and position lights using real world sizes and distances, and lighting will behave more realistically.

Comment: Regarding alpha channels in normal maps, I just checked it looks like some engines used it for layering different maps together. Personally I think it's a bad idea but that would explain why there are nmaps with alpha around. Blender doesn't support this, so always turn alpha off for those maps

Comment: I don't know who downvoted the solutuon, but it wasn't me. Regardless thanks Matt Ferndz and Gez, you guys really saved my day. Thanks!